# how do you take arguments for execv || execl to run either one program or pipe another

Tags: c

Okay I don't want to pass arguments I know that but I am trying to figure out how to pass these arguments from the terminal and where do you learn this?

```
int 
main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int infd, outfd, bytes;
    char buf[SIZE];

    //I WILL READ FILES HERE 
    while((bytes = read(infd, buf, SIZE)) > 0) {
        write(outfd, buf, bytes);
    }

    int fd[2];
    if (pipe(fd) == -1) return 1;

    int pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 < 0) return 2; 

    if (pid1 == 0) {
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execvp("How do i take arguments here?");
        // Example, I am showing an example with execl but i would like to use execv
        // Assuming wcat is my written program. Am writing wcat in another file? or 
        // can i call the wcat function if wcat was as an argument? I tried something like below
        // Note: that i tried :
        /*
            execlp("./wcat", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]); but this does nothing 
        */
        execlp("wcat", "wcat", "file1", "file2", "file3", NULL);
        if ((strcmp(argv[0], "wcat"), 0)) { // i did this but nope 
            // do something
        }
    }

    int pid2 = fork();
    if (pid2 < 0) return 3;

    if (pid2 == 0) {
        dup2(fd[2], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execvp("How do i take arguments here?");
        // Note: that i tried :
        /*
            execlp("./ww", argv[1], NULL); but this does nothing 
        */
        if ((atoi(argv[1], "pass integer here"), 0)) { // i did this but nope 
            // do something
        }
        // Example, I am showing an example with execl but i would like to use execv
        execlp("use my word-wrap program", " pass second arguments as an integere");
    }
 // you have to close the both file descriptors for the program to end
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
    // calling waitpid for fd[1] to work before starting fd[2]
    waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0);
    waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

#### **I want to run this at the terminal :**

#### **./wcat file1 file2 file3 | ./ww 50**

Please any knowledge will be helpful. my other programs are done. I just need to run this on the terminal I can pass the arguments in the file and that is fine but I want to run this at the terminal.

Comment: When you tried `execlp("./wcat", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3])`, was it exactly that, or did you actually remember the final `(char*) NULL`?

Comment: Sorry no, i did have NULL as the last argument. I was just trying to make an example and forgot to put NUll at the end

Comment: I'd try `strace -f` on the program to narrow down what's happening at that failing `execlp`.

Comment: Note if the first argument contains a slash like `"./wcat"`, then the `exec` family functions with and without a `p` in the name act mostly the same. If it's a plain name without slash like `"wcat"`, then the `p` functions including `execlp` and `execvp` will look on `$PATH`, but `.` probably isn't / shouldn't be in `$PATH`. The functions without `p` will look in the current directory.

Comment: Did you read the man page for `execvp`?  What didn't you understand there?

Comment: @dbush the only thing I am confused at is since I'm running wcat program with arguments and pipe with ww another program. what am I calling this file and run at the terminal ./wcat file1 file2 file3 | ./ww 50. I get that when execlp or execvp is run then nothing runs afterward. My confusion what do i call the file and run the other programs or im looking at this wrong.

Comment: @dbush how do i run this file to run those two files? that is the confusion i have. Please sir I am so confused and i can not find anything online to help me with confusion so i came here. Everything is done i just have to run all at once from the terminal and im so confused how i do it. I tried so many ways

Comment: regarding: ` while((bytes = read(infd, buf, SIZE)) > 0) {`  1) the variable: `infd` is used before being initialized.  2) the variable `SIZE` is used before being initialized

Answer (score 1):

`execlp` takes a variable number of arguments of type `const char *` terminated by NULL:

```
execlp("./wcat", "./wcat", "first arg", "second arg", NULL);
```

The actual issue is that you expect the code after the `execlp()` call to be executed.  It will not as the program you specified is now running instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    execlp("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", "-c", "echo hello", 0);
    printf("world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

will only print:

```
hello
```

Comment: wouldn't ./wcat would be the first argv[0] then argv[1] be file1?

Comment: The first "wcat" is the program being executed, and the 2nd the argv[0] argument being passed to the program (afaik).

Comment: `execlp("wcat", argv[0], ...)` will run a program `wcat` on `$PATH` and tell it that it was called using the same name as the current program. `execlp(argv[0], ...)` is likely to run the current program again from the start, recursively.

Comment: @aschepler Well, it behaved exactly as I expected when I tested it.  It executes path and passes whatever the first argument is to the program as argv[0].  Here is what the man page says about arg "The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed."

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it. I am confused about one thing and that is if I have my program wcat in one file and ww in another file. What do I call this file and run ./wcat file1 file2 file3 | ./ww 50? technically its three files that are being run right?

Comment: Do I name the file wcat where I write the program to call those two programs? that is called wcat and ww

Comment: @Amir your code and what you said you said you want to run `./wcat file1 file2 file3 | ./ww 50` is inconsistent.  I suspect you want your code you shared with us to be called wcat, and the to use ww as the program that you want to execute.

Comment: @ Allan Wind Instead, write a program wcat that takes a positive integer and one or more file names as arguments. For each file, it will use fork to spawn a child process, and the child process will use execl or execv to execute ww for a single file, using the provided integer as the page width. Ensure that a blank line separates the last paragraph of one file from the first paragraph of the next.

Comment: @Allan Wind so based on what my professor said and what you saying. I am writing wcat where im reading the files and then i will fork a child process to pipe ww to run. and so im only going to run wcat as the main program. I am just trying to run this on terminal is what i have issue with trying to get my toughts together.

Comment: @Amir Okay, that sounds like you want your program called wcat to have a loop over its arguments (`argv[i]`), and inside the loop do a `fork`/`exec`/`waitpid` once to run ./ww.